# Citing author's full name in biblatex

Tags: biblatex, citing

How can I cite an authors full name (= first name + last name) in `biblatex`?

```
@book{Gladwell2005,
    author = {Gladwell, Malcolm},
    address = {New York, NY},
    publisher = {Back Bay Books},
    title = {Blink: The Power of Thinking Without Thinking},
    year = {2005},
}
```

I would then like to cite the book with Malcolm Gladwell's full name. So what I'm looking for is some sort of `\citefullauthorname` macro.

Answer (score 25):

One may use `\DeclarenameAlias{labelname}{<whatever>}` inside new author-citation commands.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{biblatex}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\citeauthorfirstlast}
  {\boolfalse{citetracker}%
   \boolfalse{pagetracker}%
   \DeclareNameAlias{labelname}{first-last}%
   \usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\ifciteindex
     {\indexnames{labelname}}
     {}%
   \printnames{labelname}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\citeauthorlastfirst}
  {\boolfalse{citetracker}%
   \boolfalse{pagetracker}%
   \DeclareNameAlias{labelname}{last-first}%
   \usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\ifciteindex
     {\indexnames{labelname}}
     {}%
   \printnames{labelname}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{Knu86,
  author = {Knuth, Donald E.},
  year = {1986},
  title = {The \TeX book},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

\citeauthorfirstlast{Knu86}

\citeauthorlastfirst{Knu86}

\citeauthor{Knu86}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Or just use: `\newrobustcmd*{\citefirstlastauthor}{\AtNextCite{\DeclareNameAlias{labelname}{first-last}}\citeauthor}`.

Comment: Could someone expand Audrey's suggestion into a full MWE here? I'm not quite sure what the suggestions entails.

Comment: I have tried and it does not work.

Comment: @Audrey’s suggestion works perfectly well, but for some reason copy&pasting the code results in zero-width spaces at random positions, which breaks the code. You have to remove the zero-width spaces or just retype the code.

Comment: Name format 'first-last' deprecated.

Use the following instead:
`\newrobustcmd*{\citefirstlastauthor}{\AtNextCite{\DeclareNameAlias{labelname}{given-family}}\citeauthor}`

Answer (score 16):

You can define your own cite commands, like this commands, which will print all names in full;

```
\DeclareCiteCommand*{\citeauthor}
{\defcounter{maxnames}{99}%
\defcounter{minnames}{99}%
\defcounter{uniquename}{2}%
\boolfalse{citetracker}%
\boolfalse{pagetracker}%
\usebibmacro{prenote}}
{\ifciteindex{\indexnames{labelname}}{}%
\printnames{labelname}}
{\multicitedelim}
{\usebibmacro{postnote}}
```

that you can use it like `\citeauthor*{Gladwell2005}` (be sure to use the starred version).

[Source](http://newsgroups.derkeiler.com/Archive/Comp/comp.text.tex/2010-12/msg00186.html)

Comment: Isn't there any simpler way? A predefined command perhaps, which can achieve this? It should exist, because some bibliography styles can print the full author's name.

Comment: I only get the last name, like `Gladwell`, when trying this one. With and without the starred version.

Comment: [According to the biblatex doc](http://www.texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/biblatex/biblatex.pdf) that should already be pre-defined (added in 2013) or do I read that wrong? (Does not work in my case though.)

Answer (score 6):

Here's how I did it:

```
\nocite{reid1806analysis} Thomas Reid (1806, p.~91) pointed out the same problem
and reprimanded Aristotle severely for this and other errors.
```

Yes, this introduces redundancy and a chance of error if I change the Reid citation. But it generates the correct output, it required no debugging of LaTeX/BibTeX arcana, and I have a Ph.D. to finish.

Comment: I, too, have a Ph.D. to finish. So why am I leaving this comment? Anyway, I'd think the following would be a little better: `Thomas \citet[91]{reid1806analysis} pointed out...`

Comment: I hope you guys finished your PhD. If not yet, good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the kind words, @hola! I'm just now finishing up the research and will soon be diving back into TeX…

Comment: @BenKovitz Good luck, pal. There are multiple errors in my thesis (the PDF looks normal though), was scratching my head over this. Then I found your comment, "I have a Ph.D. to finish". I shrugged, and decided to ignore those.