# Cite Author's Full Name

Tags: bibliographies, citing, natbib

I'd like to generate a linked citation with a full author's name.

For instance, if I use

```
According to \citet{bob2000} apples are tasty.
```

And run with `hyperref`, I get the author's last name and a nice hyperlink to the bibliography. But I want the author's full name!

How can I achieve this? (BibLaTeX is also an option, but equally mysterious on this point.)

Comment: Since you mentioned that `biblatex` is an option, perhaps this post will help you: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24979/citing-authors-full-name-in-biblatex

Answer (score 34):

As it turned out, in this particular instance it worked well enough for me to modify the BibTeX source itself:

```
@misc{bob2000,
  title={An exposition on the tastiness of apples},
  author={{Bob T. Smith}}
}
```

Note the double brackets `{{` and `}}` in the entry, which cause display of the full author string, rather than some formatting thereof.

Comment: Congrats on finding this solution. The method you've found is called treating the author's name as if it were the name of a corporation. While it'll work to create the citation in the way you need, you may not like the fact that this author will now be listed in the references under B for Bob rather than under S for Smith. A solution is available, fortunately: see http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/31411/5001 for an example. Just insert an instruction such as `\noop{smith}` in the *author* field rather than in the *year* field.

Comment: The solution method proposed in this answer has two potentially severe drawbacks. First, it requires that every name in every bib entry be modified using double braces. Second, if alphabetical sorting of the entries by *surname* rather than by first name is required, a suitable `\noopsort{...}` instruction has to be prefixed to every `author` field. Finally, if the formatting requirements should ever change, all the preceding edits of the `author` fields must be undone. In general, it seems like a much better idea to pursue a solution that modifies the bibliography style file suitably.

Answer (score 12):

Define your own command where the `labelname`, the one printed by `biblatex` on `\citeauthor`, becomes `given-family`, that is, the first and the last name.

```
\newrobustcmd*{\citefirstlastauthor}{\AtNextCite{\DeclareNameAlias{labelname}{given-family}}\citeauthor}
```

**Example:**

[image: result of main.tex compiling]

The `main.tex` file

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[natbib=true,sortcites=no]{biblatex}

%\citeauthor prints only the last name. This command prints first and last name.
\newrobustcmd*{\citefirstlastauthor}{\AtNextCite{\DeclareNameAlias{labelname}{given-family}}\citeauthor}

\addbibresource{library.bib}

\begin{document}

This is a citation from \citefirstlastauthor{knuth2001things}:

``The assumption that the Bible is God's word is an unprovable axiom%
  that I tend to find confirmed as I look at it.'' \citeauthor[p. 191]{knuth2001things}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

The `library.bib` file

```
@book{knuth2001things,
  title={Things a computer scientist rarely talks about},
  author={Knuth, Donald Ervin},
  year={2001},
  publisher={Csli Publications Stanford, CA}
}
```

Comment: As I'm using a different citation style, the author name appears in all caps and surrounded by parenthesis. Is it possible to get the author name in another style?

Comment: Excellent answer! Works perfectly (and without parenthesis or all caps) with `\usepackage[style=alphabetic, backend=bibtex]{biblatex}` and even with `\textcite` instead of `\citeauthor`.

Comment: @F1iX Glad to hear my posted answer was a blessing to you. Thanks for thanking. God bless you!