# citing first name on top of family name while using \cite

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, citing, natbib

I am using natbib for citations. And I want to dislpay the whole name of the author while citing in the body of the text

```
\citep{smith1990}
```

give usually only the family name (Smith, 1990).

I want an option that would display the whole name something like: (John Smith,1990). It seems as an obvious question but I cannot find the correct trick.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Which bibliography style do you use? (It's the bibliography style, and not natbib, that determines things such as the name labels used in citation call-outs.)

Comment: Hi, thanks. I use plainnat .... My problem is not the bibliography in itself at the end of a report. But the citation in the body of the text......!

Comment: @Claude, I am not familiar with plainnat, but you may want to check if it still sticks to the specs to cite that way. In case it does or it isn't really important, you may use double braces for the author in your .bib, as explained here: [http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/85966/cite-authors-full-name]

Comment: @Rafael: thanks, the trick of putting double braces, works perfectly!!!!!

Comment: @Rafael  - The method proposed in the link you've provided has the following, potentially serious, drawback: The entries will be sorted in the bibliography by the authors' *first names* instead of their last names.

Comment: I'm proposing that this posting be re-opened since it's, in fact, *not* a duplicate -- let alone an exact duplicate -- of [Cite Author's Full Name](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/85966/5001).

Answer (score 1):

The formatting of the names used in the citation call-outs is governed not by the `natbib` package but by the bibliography style that's in use.

I'm assuming that you'll want to show the first names of all authors, rather than just those of of selected authors. While you're at it, I'll also assume that you'd want to show any "junior" name components, if present. Finally, you'll want the entries still sorted by author's surnames rather than by their first names, right?

Since you're using the `plainnat` bibliography style, I suggest you proceed as follows:

- Find the file `plainnat.bst` in your TeX distribution and make a copy of this file. Call the copy, say, `plainnat-full.bst`. (Don't edit or modify a file from the TeX distribution directly.)
- Open the file `plainnat-full.bst` in a text editor. The editor you use for your tex files will do fine.
- In `plainnat-full.bst`, locate the function `format.lab.names`. (In my copy of the the file, this function starts on line 1101.)
- In this function, replace the line

  ```
  s #1 "{vv~}{ll}" format.name$
  ```

  with

  ```
  s #1 "{ff }{vv~}{ll}{, jj}" format.name$
  ```
- Still in the same function, replace the line

  ```
              { " and " * s #2 "{vv~}{ll}" format.name$ * }
  ```

  with

  ```
              { " and " * s #2 "{ff }{vv~}{ll}{, jj}" format.name$ * }
  ```
- If you don't want to show the "junior" components, leave off the `{, jj}` substrings in the preceding two steps.
- Save the file `plainnat-full.bst`, and store it either in the directory  that contains your main .tex file or in a directory that's searched by BibTeX. If you select the latter option, be sure to update the filename database of your TeX distribution as well.
- In your main tex file, change the instruction `\bibliographystyle{plainnat}` to `\bibliographystyle{plainnat-full}` and recompile the document by re-running LaTeX, BibTeX, and LaTeX twice more to fully propagate all changes.

Happy BibTeXing!

---

[image]

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{bibx.bib}
@misc{smith:3001,
  author = "Smith, Jr., John and Smythe, III, Anna",
  title  = "Thoughts",
  year   = 3001,
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{plainnat-full}

\begin{document}
\citet{smith:3001}

\citep{smith:3001}
\bibliography{bibx}
\end{document}
```