# Bibtex: citation author a named group beginning with “The”, reduces to “T. …”

Tags: bibtex

I have a reference written by a large collaboration, which asks to be cited not with a list of individual authors, but instead with author given as a single named group, say “The Springfield Algebra Project.”

My bibitem is currently:

```
@book{xyz:book,
  author = {The {Springfield Algebra Project}},
  title = {The Little Book of Algebra}
}
```

This comes out fine in bibstyles that give the full author name: either as *“The Springfield Algebra Project”* or *“Springfield Algebra Project, The”*, both of which are OK.

However, I’m submitting to a conference whose bibstyle prints first-names as initials, and in that, it comes out as *“T. Springfield Algebra Project”*, which obviously is not so good.  Is there any way to annotate my bibitem so that it comes out better?  Specifically, I’d like to have:

- the citation is still alphabetised under *Springfield*
- the initial *The* is spelled out in full, either before or after the rest of the group name.

I have no control over the bibstyle — it’s provided by the conference.

Comment: take a look at the `key` field in the bibtex documentation.

Answer (score 4):

Found a solution just after posting, based on the comments on [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/86085), which in turn are based on [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/31411/1635):

- define (in the main document preamble) a no-op command, `\newcommand{\sortas}[1]{}`
- in the bibitem, list the `author` as `{{\sortas{Springfield Algebra Project}The Springfield Algebra Project}}`.

The double brackets tell bibtex to read the whole thing as the “surname”.  For sorting purposes, it then ignores the macro and reads the content as `Springfield Algebra ProjectThe Springfield Algebra Project`; but in the output, LaTeX heeds the macro and discards its contents, giving just *The Springfield Algebra Project* as desired.

Comment: Giving this since it worked, but leaving it unaccepted for now in case anyone has a less hacky answer.

Comment: Not hackish at all. In fact, it's what I would have recommended doing. :-)