# Get value of author from citation

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies

Is it possible to get the name of an author from a citation? I do not want to change my bibliography style and only want to do this sometimes.

Example:

```
@article{doe2014lorem,
  title={Lorem Ipsum},
  author={John Doe},
  journal={The Journal}
}
```

And then I would like a command to print "John Doe", for instance `printauthor{doe2014lorem}`, which would then print "John Doe".

Comment: Do you mean something like `\citeauthor{doe2014lorem}`? See section 3.8.5 of the `biblatex` manual.

Comment: @DavidPurton That will print 'Doe', though, and not 'John Doe'.

Comment: If you want to use the full name "Jon Doe", have a look at this answer: [link](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24979/citing-authors-full-name-in-biblatex)